# Сортировка товаров по наличии связей

Tags: mysql, laravel

Есть список товаров в которых есть связь с таблицей акций

```
public function promo()
{
    return $this->hasOne(PromoProduct::class);
}
```

Необходимо сделать выборку в которой вначале выведутся товары с акцией , а потом те у которых нет акции

```
public function scopePromo($builder)
{
    return $builder->where(function ($query) {
        $query->has('promo');
    })->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query->doesnthave('promo');
    });
}
```

Как правильно отсортировать товары?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так. Пример:

```
$result_arr = \App\Product::withCount('promo')->get()->sortByDesc('promo_count')->toArray();
```

В результате первыми в списке будут те продукты у которых есть промо. Так же в результирующий массив добавится колонка `promo_count`

Answer (score 0):

[Ordering](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

```
public function scopePromo($builder)
{
    return $builder->orderBy('promo', 'desc');
}
```

Все записи с NULL уйдут в конец.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так сделал.

```
 $queryBuilder->leftJoin('promos', function (JoinClause $join) {
                $join->on('products.id', '=', 'promos.product_id')
                        ->whereExists(function (\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $query)    {
                            $query->orderBy('promos.position');
                        });
            });
```